# Echoing vue.js data with laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.1, vue.js

I am currently echoing some data from vue.js in laravel like so:

```
<a href="/beers/@{{ beer.id }}">
    <img src="@{{ beer.path }}" alt=""/>
</a>
```

It works but my console gives me the following error twice:

> http://beerquest.dev/%7B%7B%20beer.path%20%7D%7D

Any other variables that I have printed out work fine because they are not within double quotes probably.

Funny enough everything seems to work fine though but I would like to get rid of the messy console messages. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: What is the path of your image? and can I see your routes?

Comment: Well the actual path is: path: "/uploads/heineken.jpg"

I found out the %7B means a brace so there is something wrong with the way I am using templating probably.

Comment: Can i see your routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try without @ sign

```
<a href="/beers/{{ beer.id }}">
    <img src="{{ beer.path }}" alt=""/>
</a>
```

> > @ symbol will be removed by Blade; however, {{ name }} expression will remain untouched by the Blade engine, allowing it to instead be rendered by your JavaScript framework.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#displaying-data